# AttributeError occurred when one module calls another to load a pickle

Tags: python, package, pickle

Suppose I've got pickle file `foo.pkl` depending on the classes defined in `foo.py`. I've got also a module `load_foo.py` with a function to load `foo.pkl`:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from foo import *

def load():
  pkl_path = ...
  return joblib.load(pkl_path)
```

`foo.pkl`, `foo.py`, and `load_foo.py` are located in the same package. When I invoke `load` it works fine.

Now I am writing a new module `test_load.py` that resides in another package. It imports `load_foo` and invokes `load`. In this case `load` fails with `AttributeError` as `foo.py` was not imported.

Do you why it happens and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how `pickle` works.

To unserialize an instance you have to import the related class. So you just need to add in `test_load.py`:

```
from foo import *
```

(or at least `from foo import TheClassName`).

Comment: It did not work when I added `from foo import *` to `test_load`. Thanks anyway ...